# SSH Server sending different Keys for authentication (RSA & ECDSA) & in RSA mode unable to login

Tags: ssh, rsa, ecdsa

Came across an SSH key based issue :

SSH Client : HALP-GRDB

SSH Server (has 2 IPs for management & service) : 10.100.113.55 and 
                                                  10.100.114.55

**SSH to the Server IP 10.100.113.55**

```
[root@HALP-GRDB .ssh]# ssh rapid@10.100.113.55
The authenticity of host '10.100.113.55 (10.100.113.55)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is c8:d7:70:6c:1b:13:99:d8:76:0b:dc:25:84:a1:e7:86.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.100.113.55' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rapid@10.100.113.55's password:
[rapid@HALP-MSERV1 ~]$
```

All is good and am able to login via ECDSA Key

**Now SSH to the alternate IP 10.100.114.55**

Things get weirder ,

And RSA key has been asked for auth

```
> [root@HALP-GRDB .ssh]# ssh rapid@10.100.114.55 The authenticity of
> host '10.100.114.55 (10.100.114.55)' can't be established. RSA key
> fingerprint is c8:b7:31:02:75:b5:48:12:ef:9a:d7:95:91:0d:c0:f5. Are
> you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning:
> Permanently added '10.100.114.55' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
> ################################################################################
>                                 !!!!! WARNING !!!!!
>                               For authorized use only!
>                    Any unauthorized use of this system is unlawful.
>     Any use of this system may be logged or monitored without further notice.
>                                 !!!!! WARNING !!!!!
> ################################################################################                            User Authentication Password:  User Authentication Password: User
> Authentication Password:
  Authentication Password:
  Authentication Password:
Received disconnect from 10.100.114.55: 2:
> The connection is closed by SSH server
```

And even after entering the correct password , am kicked out

Server side sshd_config file :

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
PermitRootLogin no
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 600
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Server side ssh_config file :

```
[root@HALP-MSERV1 .ssh]# cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#       $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.30 2016/02/20 23:06:23 sobrado Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication yes
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#
# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
# Host *.local
#   CheckHostIP no

Host *
        GSSAPIAuthentication yes
# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
# Send locale-related environment variables
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
        SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
        SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
        SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

Appreciate your expert opinions for the rectification of the same .

Thanks !!

Comment: Either you have something simple like wrong key, wrong password, ... or the host you connect to is not the host you think you connect to (wrong routing, wrong IP, ...).

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).
Server configuration questions probably belong on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)